# Why does this code cause "this reference" to escape implicitly?

Tags: java, reference, escaping, this, java.util.concurrent

What does "When the inner EventListener instance is published,so is the enclosing ThisEscape instance." mean?

This quote is from 《java Concurrency in Practice》

```
public class ThisEscape {
public ThisEscape(EventSource source)
{
    source.registerListener(
            new EventListener(){
                public void onEvent(Event e)
                {
                    doSomething(e);
                }
            }
    );
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ThisEscape` instance is published during construction because `doSomething` is a method of `ThisEscape` , which can cause unforeseen problems.

A simple code example, when a event occurs, the `ThisEscape` object has not yet been built, but since this `ThisEscape` is registered with the `EventSource`, then `onSomeThing` method is triggered, and an `NPE` is generated because `ThisEscape#data` has not yet been initialized:

```
public class ThisEscape {
    static class EventSource {
        private List<EventListener> eventListeners = new ArrayList<>();
        public void registerListener(EventListener eventListener) {
            eventListeners.add(eventListener);
        }
        public void eventHappen(Event event) {
            eventListeners.forEach(eventListener -> {
                eventListener.onEvent(event);
            });
        }
    }
    static class Event {
        public String eventString;
        public Event(String eventString) {
            this.eventString = eventString;
        }
    }
    interface EventListener {
        void onEvent(Event e);
    }
    private List<String> data;
    public void doSomething(Event e) {
        data.add(e.eventString);
    }
    public ThisEscape(EventSource source) {
        source.registerListener(
                new EventListener() {
                    public void onEvent(Event e) {
                        doSomething(e);
                    }
                }
        );
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        this.data = new ArrayList<>();
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventSource eventSource = new EventSource();
        new Thread(() -> {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(500);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            eventSource.eventHappen(new Event("hello"));
        }).start();
        ThisEscape thisEscape = new ThisEscape(eventSource);
    }
}
```